# *** missing separator. Stop. Make file in c

Tags: eclipse, makefile, gnu-make, eclipse-cdt

I'm getting this error:

```
make:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Line7:

```
$(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

Here is the code:

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0
OBJS =      main.c
LIBS =
TARGET =      main.exe

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
all:    $(TARGET)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: i modified code to be:'CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0
OBJS =      main.c
LIBS =
TARGET =      main.exe

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
 TAB$(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
all:$(TARGET)                      
clean:
TAB rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)' but i still have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The target actions must have an initial `TAB` character - not spaces.

```
$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

^^^^
TAB
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
^^^^
TAB
```

Comment: thanks for your help but when i applied this it gave me the same error?

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean ? 
do you mean i write TAB before clean? , i did this but i still have the same error.

Comment: insert TAB (with no spaces) before `$(CXX)` and before `rm -f`.

Comment: TAB $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
     
clean:
TAB rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET) 
do you mean that?,i am sorry i cannot get it i have the same problem?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. All command lines (i.e. gcc, rm etc.) must have `TAB` as the first character of the line.

Comment: See the rules section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29 for more clarification.